# Line chart of JQPlot time issue in X-axix

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need your favor to resolve an issue from my code. So, Let me explain about that which is I'm facing in "Line chart of JQPlot". I'm using this jqplot plugin to develop an info chart in live. Firstly, I have developed only for live. That was working properly along with time. Secondly I tried to include one more feature for that, to display live value with past one hour data. Its not working but I'm getting all past data in that line chart as you can see in the screen shot.

If I'm adding values alone to the array variable `(storedData.push(".$row1[$_POST['parameters1']].");)` in JavaScript its working live followed by past one hour data also getting x axis with numbers instead the time.

But I want to display the live with past one hour data. Note : Time should be displayed in x axix.

Here I have attached the image so please look at this code and give me solution for this.

Thanks in advance..:-Dillibabu K)

[Here is the screenshot :](http://facebookcomi.pcriot.com/ss.png) http://facebookcomi.pcriot.com/ss.png

```
<?php
$metersparameters = $_POST['parameters1'] = "WAvg";
$meters = array("Frunace 1/2");

$quer1 = mysql_query("select scanDateTime,".$_POST['parameters1']." from parameterslog where scanDateTime>'2013-08-10 10:00:01' and scanDateTime<'2013-08-10 10:50:05'") or die(mysql_error());

echo "<script>
    var storedData = [];";
    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($quer1))
        echo "storedData.push(['".date("H:i:s", strtotime($row1['scanDateTime']))."',".$row1[$_POST['parameters1']]."]);";
        //echo "storedData.push([".date("m/d/Y H:m", strtotime($row1['scanDateTime'])).",".$row1[$_POST['parameters1']]."]);";
        //echo "storedData.push(".$row1[$_POST['parameters1']].");";//This is working but time is displaying
echo "</script>";
?>

<script>
function plot()
{
    //Try1 ------
    var chartvalues=<?php echo json_encode($Values); ?>;
    var metersparameters = <?php echo json_encode($metersparameters); ?>;
    var totalmetersparameters = metersparameters.length;
    //var DataSeriesToPlot = [[12,12:22:00],[13,12:32:00],[14,12:42:00],[15,12:52:00]];
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function($)
    {
        var s = "[new Array(1)]";
        var plot1,plot2,plot3,plot4,plot5;
        function renderGraph()
        {
            <?php
            for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++)
            {
                if ($i < count($meter))
                { ?>
                    if(plot<?php echo $i+1;?>)
                        plot<?php echo $i+1;?>.destroy();
                    plot<?php echo $i+1;?> = $.jqplot('chart<?php echo $i+1;?>', [storedData],
                    {
                        legend:
                        {
                            show: true,
                            placement: 'inside'
                        },
                        series: [
                        {
                            label: metersparameters[<?php echo $i;?>]
                        },
                        {
                            yaxis: 'y2axis',
                            label: 'fdg',
                            showMarker: true,
                            fill: false,
                            neighborThreshold: 3,
                            lineWidth: 0.2,
                            color: '#0571B6',
                            fillAndStroke: true,
                            rendererOptions: {
                                smooth: true
                            }}],
                        axes: {
                            xaxis: {
                                renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                                tickOptions: {
                                    formatString: '%H:%M:%S'
                                },
                                numberTicks: 12,
                                 label: "Time"
                            //  tickInterval:'1 seconds'
                            },
                            //yaxis: {
                              //label: "Value"
                            //},
                            y2axis: {
                                min: -1.12,
                                max: 3.12,
                                tickOptions: {
                                    formatString: "%.3f"
                                },
                                numberTicks: 10
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    <?php
                }
            } ?>
        }

        var charts = new Array("chart1","chart2","chart3","chart4","chart5");
        var variables = [];
        <?php
        for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++)
        { 
            if ($i < count($meter))
            { ?>
            //plot1 = $.jqplot('chart<?php echo $i+1;?>', [storedData]);
            //plot<?php echo $i+1;?> = $.jqplot(eval("charts["+<?php echo $i;?>+"]"), eval(s), {
            plot<?php echo $i+1;?> = $.jqplot(eval("charts["+<?php echo $i;?>+"]"), [storedData], {
            //plot1 = $.jqplot("chart1", [storedData], {
            //  title: 'Live Data',
                legend: {
                    show: true,
                    placement: 'inside'
                },
                series: [
                {
                    label: metersparameters[<?php echo $i;?>]
                },
                {
                    yaxis: 'y2axis',
                    label: 'fdg',
                    showMarker: true,
                    fill: false,
                    neighborThreshold: 3,
                    lineWidth: 0.2,
                    color: '#0571B6',
                    fillAndStroke: true,
                    rendererOptions: {
                        smooth: true
                    }}],
                axes: {
                    xaxis: {
                        renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                        tickOptions: {
                            formatString: '%H:%M:%S'
                        },
                        numberTicks: 12,
                         label: "Time"
                    //  tickInterval:'1 seconds'
                    },
                    //yaxis: {
                      //label: "Value"
                    //},
                    y2axis: {
                        min: -1.12,
                        max: 3.12,
                        tickOptions: {
                            formatString: "%.3f"
                        },
                        numberTicks: 10
                    }
                },
                cursor: {
                    zoom: true,
                    showTooltip: false,
                    show: true
                },
                highlighter: {
                    useAxesFormatters: false,
                    showMarker: false,
                    show: false
                },          
                highlighter: {
                    show: true, 
                    showLabel: true, 
                    showTooltip: true,
                    useAxesFormatters: true,
                    formatString: '<table class="jqplot-highlighter"> \
                                   <tr><td>Time: %s</td></tr> \
                                   <tr><td>%#.3f</td></tr></table>',
                    sizeAdjust: 7.5 ,
                    tooltipLocation : 's'
                }
            });

            variables = [];
            for(var i  = 0; i < totalmetersparameters; i++)
                variables[i] = "var myData" + i + " = [];";

            var myData0 = [], myData1 = [], myData2 = [], myData3 = [], myData4 = [];
            var x, y, samples = 0;

            for(var i  = 0; i < totalmetersparameters; i++) 
                plot<?php echo $i+1;?>.series[0].data = variables[i];

            plot<?php echo $i+1;?>.resetAxesScale();
            plot<?php echo $i+1;?>.axes.xaxis.numberTicks = 12;
            plot<?php echo $i+1;?>.axes.y2axis.numberTicks = 10;
            plot<?php echo $i+1;?>.replot();

            <?php
            }
        } ?>
        var secsBuffer = 60, refreshInterval = 1;
        var sampleWindow = secsBuffer / refreshInterval;

        $("#refreshInterval").change(function() {
            clearInterval(gint);
            gint = window.setInterval(updateSeries, $("#refreshInterval").val() * 1000);
            refreshInterval = $("#refreshInterval").val();
            sampleWindow = secsBuffer / refreshInterval;
        });

        $("#secsBuffer").change(function() {
            secsBuffer = $("#secsBuffer").val();
            sampleWindow = secsBuffer / refreshInterval;
        });

        function updateSeries()
        {
            var result;
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "includes/live/Multi_Meters_Multi_Parameters_Chart_Data.php?&parameters="+<?php echo json_encode($parameters); ?> + "&meters=" + <?php echo json_encode($meters); ?>+"",
                success: function(html)
                {
                    result = html;
                },
                async:false
            });

            var minx, maxx, miny, maxy;
            var device_values = result.split("#");
            var time, parameter, eachDevicevalues = device_values[0].split(",");
            var n = eachDevicevalues[1].replace(/-/gi, ",");
            n = n.replace(/ /gi, ",");
            n = n.replace(/:/gi, ",");
            var str = n.split(','); 
            n = new Date(str[0],str[1]-1,str[2],str[3],str[4],str[5]);

            minx = maxx = Number((n).getTime());
            miny = maxy = Number(eachDevicevalues[0]); 

            for(var i = 0; i < device_values.length; i++)
            {
                eachDevicevalues = device_values[i].split(",");
                var n = eachDevicevalues[1].replace(/-/gi, ",");
                n = n.replace(/ /gi, ",");
                n = n.replace(/:/gi, ",");
                var str = n.split(',');
                n = new Date(str[0],str[1]-1,str[2],str[3],str[4],str[5]);                  
                time = (n).getTime();                   

                if(Number(time) > maxx)
                    maxx = time;
                else if (Number(time) <= minx)  
                    minx = time;

                parameter = Number(eachDevicevalues[0]);
                if(parameter > maxy)
                    maxy = parameter;
                else if (parameter <= miny) 
                    miny =parameter;

                var vars = variables[i].split(' ');
                //alert(parameter+"="+eachDevicevalues[1]);
                storedData.push(eachDevicevalues[1].substring(19,11), parameter);
                renderGraph();
                //eval(vars[1]).push([time, parameter]);
                //eval("plot" + (i+1) +".series[0].data = eval(vars[1]);");

                //maxx = maxx + (secsBuffer * 60000);   //  to vary xaxis ticks to certain interval,
                //minx = minx - (secsBuffer * 250); //  to vary xaxis ticks to certain interval,
                maxy = maxy + 0.5;
                miny = miny - 0.5;

                eval("plot" + (i+1) +".resetAxesScale();");
                //eval("plot" + (i+1) +".axes.xaxis.numberTicks = 12;");//Test
                eval("plot" + (i+1) +".axes.y2axis.numberTicks = 10;");
                //eval("plot" + (i+1) +".axes.xaxis.min = minx;");//Test
                //eval("plot" + (i+1) +".axes.xaxis.max = maxx;");//Test
                eval("plot" + (i+1) +".axes.y2axis.max = maxy;");
                eval("plot" + (i+1) +".axes.y2axis.max = miny;");
                eval("plot" + (i+1) +".replot();");     
            }
            samples++;
        }
        gint = window.setInterval(updateSeries, refreshInterval * 3000);
    });
}
```